# How to remove empty string json values in complex json object?

Tags: c#, json, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to upload JSON values to AWS Dynamo, and it looks like it's giving me a 400-type error when I upload values that have any properties with "" as values. The app I'm writing is a C# app.

What's the best way to remove any keys that have value of ""? I've seen how to remove null values, but I'm not sure this applies.

Say:

```
{myObj: { x: "", y: "test str" }, myStr: "hello world!"}
```

Becomes:

```
{myObj: { y: "test str" }, myStr: "hello world!"}
```

Comment: What is the way to remove null values and why couldn't the logic be changed from `obj.x == null` to `obj.x == string.Empty`?

Comment: I don't want string.Empty, that's the thing. I need the entire key deleted

Comment: I'm not doing assignment, I'm just asking why the logic used to remove nulls couldn't be altered to remove properties that match `string.Empty`.

Comment: I suppose it absolutely could. I didn't know if there was a general solution provided by Json.NET, the other ones are just recursive solutions that iterate through the tree and check against values. This would totally work, but I just didn't know if there was a standard solution to this or something.

Anyway, thanks much. I'll try that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using [Newtonsoft's Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library, you can play with `JsonSerializerSettings` and `DefaultValue` attribute:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Myobj myObj { get; set; }
    public string myStr { get; set; }
}

public class Myobj
{
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string x { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string y { get; set; }
}

var originalSerializedObject = "{myObj: { x: \"\", y: \"test str\" }, myStr: \"hello world!\"}";

var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(originalSerializedObject);

var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
                             { 
                                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, 
                                DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore 
                             };

var newSerializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializedObject, serializerSettings);

Console.WriteLine(newSerializedObject);
//{"myObj":{"y":"test str"},"myStr":"hello world!"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want it to be applied to every single field, you could just add the following on the field that you would want to ignore when empty.

```
[DefaultValue("")]
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, 
DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
```